# Creating a Link to Look Like a Button

Tags: html, css

I have a Button Element that is styled with hover the way I would like it to look. However, it was suggested to me that I should use a link and style it to look like a button in order to preserve default browser button styling.

So that Ideally the button by itself does nothing, but clicking it activates its link.

I have tried to make it a link, then a link over the element, removing span, all while changing the CSS to suit `<a>` but the overall styling and hover go strange.

```
<a href="" class="g2b-button"><button>Hover Me!</button></a>

<a href="" class="g2b-button">Hover Me!</a>
```

Could anybody please help shed some light on where I'm going wrong and how to make this button element a link while still looking like the button?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

---

This Is the button element.

[Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/Rosko34/pen/vYJRBoO)

[image]

Button Element

```
<button class="g2b-button" title=""><span>Hover me!</span></button>
```

CSS

```
.g2b-button {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #A7784A;
  padding: 17px 55px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
}

.g2b-button span {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.g2b-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 490%;
  width: 140%;
  background: #31324E;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}

.g2b-button:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Why don't you simply replace `button` with `a`?
`<a class="g2b-button" title=""><span>Hover me!</span></a>`

Comment: @IvanBeliakov if you click on the code sample you can see that it makes the element behave differently.

Comment: Set `display: inline-block`; for `.g2b-button` instead of `block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `display: block` under `.g2b-button` to `display: inline-block`. This is because anchor tags (`<a>`) are treated different by the browser than button tags (`<button>`).

Comment: button inside an anchor is invalid. 2 different things for 2 different task. an anchor is for direct to another file while a button is used to trigger a script. If you need both you either have to set an onclick-trigegr or event listener to the anchor or an href to the button. Fixing the OP's issue should not be done by repeating is invalid markup.

Comment: Thanks Isaac. Seems to work; although just curious may I ask why does the blue corner not exactly match (slightly smaller) than the button element?  Please check https://codepen.io/Rosko34/pen/vYJRBoO

Comment: It looks like you just needed to adjust your `translateX` value. Updating it from `-9%` to `-8%` fixed it for me.

Comment: @tacoshy I never said to place an anchor tag inside a button. I have been providing my answer under the assumption that the button is being replaced with an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers. There is also an important syntax consideration. Buttons would be used for forms or accordions or card flips, opening or closing modals and other on-page dynamics, things which do not change to a different page. Links would always be used when taking a visitor to a new page. Your post vaguely suggests linking to another page so `<button>` would not be good syntax.

Comment: 90% is external off page. However, If you do not recommend using class I’d inside <A> tags, Can you offer a solution to the original post for internal linking? He. How would you add a internal link for on-page elements to a button? Thanks

Comment: @Ross Think of it this way. `<a>` tags are **links** to some resource, whether that be another section of the same page, a separate page in the same site, or something on another site entirely. `<button>` tags are **actions** that the user can perform, whether that be saving some data they edited or sending an instant message. They are intended to perform different tasks, but since they can do the same thing with enough mucking about it's up to you to use them properly.